# Dell PowerEdge R510 SATA drives appearing as SAS

Tags: raid, boot, dell-poweredge, dell-perc

I have a Dell PowerEdge R510 with the following:

- PERC H700
- 2 x 500GB cabled SATA drives (RAID 1)
- 6 x 3 TB SAS hot swap drives (5 in RAID 6)

I was testing an online expansion of the RAID array using MegaRAID, in doing so I stupidly added the final SAS drive to an array that contains the SATA drives.  I've read that this wouldn't be possible via the RAID BIOS, but it's certainly doable with MegaRAID!  I removed the drive and have now re-set the configuration of the SATA drives to RAID1.  The thing is, they're not appearing in the boot menu (so effectively I cannot boot, booting from a liveUSB results in either a kernel panic or other nasty errors) and, when I check the RAID controller BIOS, I see that they're listed as SAS drives now.  Does anyone know if this could be causing the problem with booting (and, if so, suggest a fix)?

Cheers,

Matt